# Laravel loading the same login page on login

Tags: php, database, laravel, sqlite, authentication

When I try to login, it was working earlier, but now when I click on login it loads the same login page again. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Login.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Login') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                                        {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Login') }}
                                </button>

                                @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                        {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                                    </a>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

RegisterController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

LoginContainer

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::view('users','users');
Route::post('users','Users@index');
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/profile/{user}', 'ProfilesController@index')->name('profile.show');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

If any other code is required please let me know I will update my question. I am using laravel and sqlite as database, but it keep loading the same login page on login rather transferring to some different page

Comment: so you submit the form and you get redirected back to the login form again?

Comment: @lagbox yes, that's right.

Comment: normally that would be validation failing and redirecting back but you seem to be checking for these errors ... you didn't by any chance assign the `auth` middleware to the `login` POST route did you?

Comment: Yeah, I try creating the new user as well and it's still the same so I doubt it's any error. Can you tell me where that file is where I might have accidently assigned the auth middleware to login? @lagbox

Comment: you can run `php artisan route:list` and see what middleware is assigned to that particular route

Comment: I get this error: 
   `Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException 

  Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Users] does not exist.` @lagbox

Comment: @iachi can you show your controller code which you are using for login ?

Comment: please show the controller code, it's definitely just because of validation

Comment: @KhalidKhan Well there is so many file in controller code. What exactly one you want me to upload?

Comment: @iachi the one where you pass your form data

Comment: @KhalidKhan I am not sure which one is that. But in my controllers-auth I have confirmpassword, forgetpassword, logincontroller, registercobtroller, verificationcontroller, homecontroller, controller, profilescontroller. Which one do you want? Sorry I am new to it so not sure

Comment: @iachi It's Okay no need to be sorry, Paste the code for your login controller

Comment: @KhalidKhan Did. Please have a look.

Comment: @iachi, bro it's looking fine here because It's default one. Just change your $redirectTo to a route where you want to send your user after successful login

Comment: @KhalidKhan I am redirecting to home, but it does not seem to rediect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220417/discussion-between-khalid-khan-and-iachi).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are being redirected because the validation is failing.

Enable error reporting in your `.env` file by changing `APP_DEBUG=false` to `APP_DEBUG=true`

You can as well include error messages in your blade to give you a better idea of what is wrong.

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Also, ensure you include `use App\User` in your controller in case you are not using the default `auth` controller.

Lastly, you can share your controller here to make it easy for people to understand the issue and help you.

Cheers!

Comment: Also, there are so many controller file do you want me to upload all of them?

Comment: Okay, first add `APP_DEBUG=true` to your `.env` file. Please remember to change this back to `false` when you are done with the troubleshooting.

The easiest way for me to know which Controller you are using is to see your route file. So first, check your route file and let me see where `Route::post('login'...)` is binded to. That will give me an idea of the actual controller to check for the error. You can also check if `Auth::routes();` in your route file.

Comment: I have updated my question with web.php file please have a look